# 403 Forbidden Access to this resource is denied on server- Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.7

I'm working with a project in `Laravel 5.7`. Everything works in localhost. But, after uploading in the server, all routes for `Backend Part` is working. But post routes for `Frontend Part` is not working. It shows the error -

> 403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied

`.htaccess` in root folder is -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Have someone face this problem before? What I've missed. In localhost everything is working fine, but not in Server.

Comment: Is `Frontend Part` some blades or another project like angular?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are not generating artisan key. Please run these command on server.

```
composer update
php artisan key:generate
```

Your htaccess hould be like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$public /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Still get the 403 error. Do I need to change the .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, your .htaccess should be like this

Answer (score 1):

For handling front end stuffs in `/public` add this to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: After adding this I need to add /public after the URL. But, I don't want that

Comment: You mean you have to add /public to your url? I don't think so. Have you tried it?

Comment: Tried it. But problem may be different. I've tried to add new post routes and that's working. Not working the previous ones. I can't get a solution of this problem.

Comment: The problem is the tinMCE editor. When I remove tinyMCE it works perfectly. But I need to fix that also.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess looks fine to  me
Make sure your post routes are being called with form.

If there is no issue in your backend then

**You need to grant permissions to server of these directories**

give permissions to bootstrap/ and storage/ directory as shown below

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/ bootstrap/
```

Then it should work